# Curious behavior of globs in a bash "if" statement

Tags: arrays, bash, if-statement

I just came across this curious behavior but I could not find it documented anywhere. I am hesitant to use it in my script until I fully understand it. Could someone please explain the behavior below?

Essentially, in my `if` statement, I am inquiring whether all of the numbered files exist in the current folder and print a statement based on that reality.

---

If *only* `file1.zip` and `file3.zip` exist, this is what happens:

```sh
> if [ -s file1.zip ] && [ -s file2.zip ] && [ -s file3.zip ] && [ -s file4.zip ]
> then
>   echo All numbers[1-4] exist
> else
>   echo Only numbers[1-4] exist so far
> fi
Only numbers[1-4] exist so far
```

Which is what I would expect. However, when the statement is changed to actually match the file names in the `if` statement, something interesting happens:

```sh
> if [ -s file1.zip ] && [ -s file2.zip ] && [ -s file3.zip ] && [ -s file4.zip ]
> then
>   echo All file[1-4].zip exist
> else
>   echo Only file[1-4].zip exist so far
> fi
Only file1.zip file3.zip exist so far
```

The file names are now written out. Consistent with this behavior, when the `if` statement is condensed, the behavior repeats:

```sh
> if [[ -s file[1-4].zip ]]
> then
>   echo All file[1-4].zip exist
> else
>   echo Only file[1-4].zip exist so far
> fi
Only file1.zip file3.zip exist so far
```

---

When all the files are present, accordingly, this is what happens:

```sh
> if [ -s file1.zip ] && [ -s file2.zip ] && [ -s file3.zip ] && [ -s file4.zip ]
> then
>   echo All numbers[1-4] exist
> else
>   echo Only numbers[1-4] exist so far
> fi
All numbers[1-4] exist
```

```sh
> if [ -s file1.zip ] && [ -s file2.zip ] && [ -s file3.zip ] && [ -s file4.zip ]
> then
>   echo All file[1-4].zip exist
> else
>   echo Only file[1-4].zip exist so far
> fi
All file1.zip file2.zip file3.zip file4.zip exist
```

However, in the last case, the condensed statement for some reason evaluates as `false` but all file names are still written out:

```sh
> if [[ -s file[1-4].zip ]]
> then
>   echo All file[1-4].zip exist
> else
>   echo Only file[1-4].zip exist so far
> fi
Only file1.zip file2.zip file3.zip file4.zip exist so far
```

---

Essentially, my confusion is two-fold:

- How does the array-like behavior exactly work and why doesn't a term like `numbers[1-4]` get unfolded into individual terms but the specific name of the files (`file[1-4].zip`) does (i.e. into `file1.zip file3.zip`)?
- Why is the behavior not consistent when the `if` statement is written out (`if [ -s file1.zip ] && [ -s file2.zip ] && [ -s file3.zip ] && [ -s file4.zip ]`) vs. condensed (`if [[ -s file[1-4].zip ]]`)?

Comment: `set -x` is your friend for answering this kind of question yourself.

Comment: BTW, `[ -s file[1-4].zip ]` doesn't suppress globbing like `[[ ]]` does, but it still doesn't work the way you want, because it turns into `[ -s file1.zip file2.zip file3.zip file4.zip ]`, which isn't valid syntax to `[`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Facts:

1. `[1-4]` is a glob pattern that matches digits 1 to 4.
2. Expanding glob patterns (ex. `*.txt` or `[1-4].txt`) into a list of words is called *filename expansion*.
3. Word splitting and filename expansion are **not** performed inside `[[` `]]` arguments.

Conclusions:

1. `file[1-4].zip` when an argument of `echo` is expanded to list of files that match the pattern.
2. `[[ -s file[1-4].zip ]]` checks for a file named **literally** `file[1-4].zip`. Ie. it's the same as `[[ -s 'file[1-4].zip' ]]`.

> why doesn't a term like numbers[1-4] get unfolded into individual terms

When a glob matches no files, it is not expanded and "stays" and is passed along without any changes (except when `shopt -s nullglob`, in which case it disappears). You have no files named `numbers1` or `numbers2` or `numbers3` or `numbers4`. Create such file and `numbers[1-4]` will expand to them.

> the specific name of the files (file[1-4].zip) does

Because you have `file1.zip` and `file3.zip`. Remove those files, and it will stay.

> Why is the behavior not consistent when the if statement is writ...

Because `[[` is super specially handled by bash unlike any other command. These are very special semantics associated with `[[` `]]`. See [bash manual [[ expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_005b_005b).